# How can I grow my Chinese elm bonsai bigger?

Tags: pruning, growth, bonsai

I Bought this bonsai a few weeks ago and everything is going good (I've pruned the roots and branches, it's in a small pot, and it's even growing new leaves very fast).  There are no actual problems with it but I just want to know how can I grow it up to about a bit over 1ft tall?  I think it would be a good size and look nice in the room its in so how long will it take to grow it that tall?  And is there any way I can speed it up?  I've been fertilising it with a special bonsai fertiliser. The picture I added is the bonsai after just being pruned and watered[image: A small bonsai three in front of windows]

Comment: I spent £24 on it and i dont want to grow it any bigger then my goal but thank you for the tips ill cut down a bit on the top pruning

Comment: I suggest you put that as an answer (even from yourself) and mark it as accepted.  That does two things.  First, this question will no longer appear in the unanswered category.   Second, if any of the comments helped you but have since been deleted, what you recall will be available to a future Someone who has a similar question.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'special bonsai fertiliser'. If you asked a bonsai expert, they would tell you that this tree should be outside and not inside from the end of the last frosts until the start of the winter frosts (May to end September in the UK) after which time you bring it inside and keep it in a cool bedroom over winter. Whilst it can be kept as an indoor tree, it will not thrive indoors continuously without a lot more care, but for now it should be spending at least September in your UK garden in semi shade where it might develop more strength ready for the winter.

Comment: i bought a fertilizer that says "bonsai focus - food for bonsais" though